# Instant-on Text File Viewer

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

Are there any basic text editors available that are just drop-dead simple, that allow me to instantly view the contents of a small text file?  GEdit is nice, but it takes several seconds to start.  I need something that is extreme bare-bones that doesn't have to load a bunch of features that can pop up and show the contents in the blink of an eye.  Is there anything like that?

**Edit:** I'm looking for a GUI application that I can use to open a file from Nautilus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested a few editors by right-clicking on a text file in *nautilus*, selecting *open with/other application*

[image: screenshot]

and then clicking on *find applications online*. One I liked (apart from my standard editor, *bluefish*) was *LeafPad*, small, fast to open, nothing fancy.

Comment: Wow, that one even beat SciTe.  Super-simple.

Answer (score 4):

[Mousepad](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mousepad/) is a very small and simple text editor that starts *instantly* (literally).

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install mousepad
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI editor, try [SciTe](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEImage.html). It's a bit hard to configure, but very powerful and fast.

Comment: That's perfect!  If it started any faster, it would open before I clicked! :)  Used to use SciTe as my main editor, forgot all about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just found **gnome-sushi**  - a quick previewer for nautilus.

Highlight the file in Nautilus (so it gets focus) and hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Wow!

Comment: I tried Sushi, but wasn't very fast, and didn't allow me to select text at all.

Answer (score 0):

nano launches very fast at least in this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with `nano` and `vim`. You have to run those applications from the command line. You can also use them when you don't have a GUI.

Fastest is **Midnightcommander**. It's a file manager that runs from the command line. To start type `mc`. To view the contents of a file just hite the <kbd>F3</kbd> key.

You have to download Midnightcommander via Ubuntu Software Repository or via Synaptics.

Comment: You're right, vim and nano both start basically instantly, but I would need to start a terminal emulator, and I don't always have one up.  I'd like a GUI I can start from Nautilus.